# Disable FormGroup not working as expected

Tags: angular

When initializing a `FormGroup` and disabling the `FormGroup` or `FormControl` in a `HttpClient.get` callback, the `FormGroup` is not disabled in HTML, but the `disabled` property reports as `true`.

Please see working example [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/O1R6wnSOGqvvkRFI?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

I can fix the issue by wrapping the disabled code in a timeout as below, but this is not desirable:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.form.disable();
});
```

It does work when not setting the `FormGroup` to a new instance, but I would like to set it to a new instance.

Minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PersonService } from './person.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `  
        <form [formGroup]="form">    
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onFetchPerson()">Click Me</button>                
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Surname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="surname" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                
                Disabled:{{form.disabled}}<br>
                Status:{{form.status}}
            </div>
        </form>
    `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {  
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({     
      firstName: new FormControl(),
      surname: new FormControl(),
    });
  }

  public onFetchPerson() {
    this.personService.fetchPerson().subscribe(() => {
      this.form = new FormGroup({        
        firstName: new FormControl('John'),
        surname: new FormControl('Doe'),
      });
      this.form.disable();
      console.log(this.form);
    });
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PersonService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public fetchPerson = () => this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [App],
    bootstrap: [App],
    providers: [
        PersonService
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[image]

Comment: On your plunkr, it does not disable even with the timeout

Comment: Please check again, as you can see from the gif the green button does disable.

Comment: Ok the problem with the plunkr was the service call. It never gets into the success callback

Comment: I`m not sure what browser you are using but it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22556 the issue is still open

Comment: thanks @VinodBhavnani for the github link

Comment: NP Tjaart. Hopefully they fix this in the upcoming versions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it worked if you just set the value instead of passing a whole new instance of the formGroup

```
 this.personService.fetchPerson().subscribe(() => {
      this.form.setValue({
        firstName:'John',
        surname:'Doe'
      });
      this.form.disable();
      console.log(this.form);
    });
```

Comment: yes this does work but I need to set it to a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `ChangeDetectorRef` for your problem

here's an example

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class App implements OnInit {
    constructor(private personService: PersonService, readonly cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public onFetchPerson() {
    this.personService.fetchPerson().subscribe(() => {

      this.form = new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl('John'),
        surname: new FormControl('Doe'),
      });
      this.cd.detectChanges();
      this.form.disable();
      console.log(this.form);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that actually worked for me! I spent hours on this, and my code was perfect according to every other answer or doc I read, but still wouldn't disable. I tried researching what this actually did for me, but I couldn't figure it out. Would you mind adding some explanation to this answer on what ChangeDetectorRef does here?

Answer (score 0):

I would use FormBuilder, this is a very tidy way of creating your form and adding validation.

Having created the form, this allows you to **patch** (partially update) the form. 
To **set** values you need to have all the properties in your object.

> The FormBuilder provides syntactic sugar that shortens creating instances of a FormControl, FormGroup, or FormArray. It reduces the amount of boilerplate needed to build complex forms.

[From angular.io](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder)

[Plunk here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/uPnfC1mvC3qDaP1N?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1)

```
  import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

  constructor(
    private personService: PersonService, 
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [''],
      surname: [''],
    });
  }

  public onFetchPerson() {
    this.personService.fetchPerson().subscribe(() => {
      this.form.patchValue({ firstName: 'John', surname: 'Doe' });
      this.form.disable();
      console.log(this.form);
    });
  }
```